# Best way to access The MS-Exchange Global Access List from a .net application

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server

Which is the best way to access the corporate MS-Exchange GAL (Global Access List - The list of the corporate ID/GroupIDS) from a .net application? We could use CDO, MAPI, LDAP etc but i am looking forward to a solution which is faster and is compatible with atleast outlook 2000 and above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Accessing the GAL via System.DirectoryServices](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/frankalonzo/GlobalAddressList11262005053740AM/GlobalAddressList.aspx?ArticleID=1c1b6bf4-b468-42f6-a40b-b1f1f677dde6) might point you in the right direction, the article is from 2005 though.